# Behavior of the C++ extraction operator when used to read into a string

Tags: c++, string, iostream

I was working with some C++ code, and noticed some code of the following form:

```
ss >> str;
```

where ss is a stream (a stringstream, in this case), and str is a string.

What is the defined behavior of this code? Specifically, what is the value of str after this is executed?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Unless the `skipws` flag is set in `ss.flags()` (it is by default, but
you can unset it), white space is skipped (and not copied into `str`),
then `ss` copies text from the input until either a white space or end
of file is encountered (or it runs out of memory, or it reads
`std::string::max_size` characters).

What is white space is determined by the `ctype<char>` locale imbued in
`ss`.

Answer (score 2):

The >> operator will read up to the first whitespace character (or the end of the stream) and assigning them to str.

If your input stream contained "ab cde". Then str will equal "ab".

Answer (score 1):

The expected behavior is that the first word stored in `ss` will be consumed and stored in `str`, where *word* is the longest sequence of non-space characters according to the locale obtained after removing any leading space character from `ss`.

Answer (score 0):

It puts the bytes from ss to str.

Comment: Yes, I know that. What character, or sequence of characters, is used as the delimiter?

Comment: Extraction ends when the next character is either a valid whitespace or a null character, or if the End-Of-File is reached.

Comment: Hmm... That seems to make sense, seeing as that's how the extraction operator works with other types.

Comment: It shouldn't end with a null character, at least not if the imbued locale is the "C" locale.